# Why I can't run a plugin anycomment on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Now I try to install a plugin "anycomment" on my site. In single.php I inserted this:

```
<?php do_shortcode('[anycomment]') ?>
```

But it's not working. Why?

I attached screens with plugin:
[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B14xO.png)
[Second screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eST9e.png)

Can you help me with it? Thanks advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[anycomment]'); ?>
```